# Invoke Parameter constructor in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a sample snippet to invoke a `class` having some parameters. Below code works fine with desktop applications which targeted to the `.net framework`

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int value, string str)
    {

    }
} 

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    object[] ctorvalues = new object[2];
    ctorvalues[0] = 1;
    ctorvalues[1] = "vimal";
    Type type = typeof(MyClass);
    var info = type.GetConstructors().FirstOrDefault();
    var param = info.GetParameters();
    info.Invoke(ctorvalues);
}
```

I have to achieve the same in `Windows Store App`, I am not able to find any method to get the `constructor` info. Could anyone please help me on this. Please suggest some alternative way if possible. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there are new 'reflection' APIs you need to use for Windows Store apps (though these new APIs will also work on the desktop).  See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535795(v=vs.110).aspx